# Identifying the highest number in a row with Python

Tags: python

I have data in three columns as follows, I am trying to identify the position of the greatest value in each row (1,2,3) and also to ignore the rows where the greatest value occurs more than once. The script I have below will identify the highest value in each row but I am unable fix the other two issues. Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

```
0   3   3
3   3   3
3   3   3
0   3   3
3   4   3


data = open('file.csv', 'r')

rows = []
for line in data:
    row = [int(each) for each in line.split()]
    rows.append(row)

data.close()

columns = zip(*rows)


for index, column in enumerate(rows):
    print max(column)
```

Comment: any piece of code that you wrote and that is not working is greatly appreciated as well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all of your rows in are in a list, you can loop over that list and use a few built-ins to find the information you want:

```
gvalues = []
for row in rows:
    highest = max(row)
    tally = row.count(highest)
    position = row.index(highest)

    if tally == 1:
        gvalues.append((highest, position))
    else:
        gvalues.append((None, None))
```

Once this is finished, you will have a list `gvalues` that containes tuples of `highest value, position` for each row.  It will contain `None, None` for the rows where there are more than one of `highest`.

For the example you provided it will output `[(None, None), (None, None), (None, None), (None, None), (4, 1)]`

Answer (score 0):

Your can return a list, with a little less code using python's `count`. OP asked just for the index of the highest value, if unique.

```
    max_index = list()
    for i in a:
        if i.count(max(i))>1:
            max_index.append(None)
        else:
            max_index.append(i.index(max(i)))
```

This example returns `[None, None, None, None, 1]`